# How to prove $\sqrt{99} + \sqrt{101} < 2\sqrt{100}$ without a calculator

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation, radicals, number-comparison

This is one of my extension sheet questions and I was really stumped on how to approach it.

$\sqrt{99} + \sqrt{101} < 2\sqrt{100}$

First I had approached it by looking at smaller and larger square roots, however the numbers are much too small to be practical in an exam. I next have done the following:

Let $n = 10$

$\sqrt{n^2-1}$ + $\sqrt{n^2+1}$

$\sqrt{(n-1)(n+1)}$ + $\sqrt{n^2+1}$

But this didn't seem to workout to anything meaningful, so have left it at this. Could anyone see another approach to this question which is probably glaringly obvious?

Comment: Imagine the graph of $f(x)=\sqrt x$. How does $f(100)$ compare to the average of $f(99)$ and $f(101)$?

Comment: See [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h87618p511011). By Jensen, $\frac{\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+1}}{2}<\sqrt{n}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\sqrt{ c} − \sqrt{c − 1} \geq \sqrt{ c + 1} −\sqrt{c}$ for all real $c \geq 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447074/prove-that-sqrt-c-%e2%88%92-sqrtc-%e2%88%92-1-geq-sqrt-c-1-%e2%88%92-sqrtc-for-all-real)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sequence $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ is decreasing, as $$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$ and the square root is an increasing function.

Thus, $$\sqrt{100}-\sqrt{99}>\sqrt{101}-\sqrt{100}\implies \sqrt{99}+\sqrt{101}<2\sqrt{100}$$

Answer (score 6):

Square both sides (both are positive), you'll get:

$$200+2\sqrt{99}\sqrt{101} < 400 \implies \sqrt{99 \cdot 101} < 100 \implies \sqrt{9999} < \sqrt{10000}$$ which is true because $\sqrt{x}$ is an increasing function

Comment: I would do something to say that the original problem is your steps in reverse...  rather than $\implies $  some sort of thing saying "depends on,"   then perhaps your exact line with a reversed implies symbol. They must have one

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of an overkill, but overall another approach - define $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$. The inequality becomes:
$$\frac{f(100)-f(99)}{100-99}=f(100)-f(99)>f(101)-f(100)=\frac{f(101)-f(100)}{101-100}$$
By Lagrange IVT, the LHS is equal to $f'(c_1)$ for some $c_1\in (99,100)$ and the RHS is equal to $f'(c_2)$ for some $c_2\in (100,101)%$. As $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ is strictly decreasing, $f'(c_1)>f'(c_2)$, giving us the desired inequality.